# c++ get years between date chosen by user and actual date(counting days,months,years)

Tags: c++, datetime, time, date-difference

i tried doing this:

```
struct Den_t
{
    int day, month, year;
}; 

int main()
{
        struct Den_t* Datum = new struct Den_t;
        struct Den_t* Dnes = new struct Den_t;

    time_t theTime = time(NULL);
    struct tm aTime;
    localtime_s(&aTime, &theTime);

    Dnes->day = aTime.tm_mday;
    Dnes->month = aTime.tm_mon + 1;
    Dnes->year = aTime.tm_yday + 1900;

    cin >> Datum->day >> Datum->month >> Datum->year;
    if (Dnes->year - Datum->year >= 18 )
        cout << "full aged " << endl;
    else
        cout << "not full aged " << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

but i somehow cant understand **what should i even compare and decrement**,could someone explain me

> what else i need to do to tell people's date for example in float by
>   comparing year,month and day of actual time and date user inputs in
>   the program?

Comment: Don't implement your own date-time functions (unless it's a school assignment or similar), instead use the [functionality in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: You have a good start, but if you want to tell the exact age of a person you also have to consider the birth date as well. For example if the supposedly 18 year old is born on January 1 or December 31 does matter.

Comment: @BoPersson thats exactly what i do, i use cin to input date as "day month year" (spaces separate each) but i have no idea how to continue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these libraries:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

This is how I would tackle the problem.  First the code, then the explanation:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << "Enter birthday [day month year]:";
    int di, mi, yi;
    std::cin >> di >> mi >> yi;
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid date\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto y = year{yi};
    if (!y.ok())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid year\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto m = month(mi);
    if (!m.ok())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid month\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto d = day(di);
    if (!d.ok())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid day\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto birthday = y/m/d;
    if (!birthday.ok())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid birthday\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto local_time = current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now());
    auto today = year_month_day{floor<days>(local_time)};
    auto age = today.year() - birthday.year();
    if (birthday + age > today)
        --age;
    if (age >= years{18})
        std::cout << "full aged at " << age.count() << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "not full aged at " << age.count() << "\n";
}
```

I would first go to some trouble to check the validity of the user input.  What I have below seems like a minimum:

- It must be integral input.
- Each integral input must have a reasonable value (e.g. month must be in the range [1, 12].
- The combination y/m/d must be a valid date.

A more robust program might give the user some feedback on what he input, and give him another chance to correct his mistake.

Once assured we have a valid birthday, we need to get the current date in the local timezone.  This:

```
auto local_time = current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now());
```

gets the local time.

This local time can be converted to a local year, month and day with:

```
auto today = year_month_day{floor<days>(local_time)};
```

This computation follows the custom that your birthday begins at the local midnight, regardless of what time of day (and where on the planet) you were actually born.  In other words, once the local year/month/day is established, this problem is independent of the local time zone, and even the local time of day.

Next, the current age is computed:

```
auto age = today.year() - birthday.year();
if (birthday + age > today)
    --age;
```

The difference between the years of today and the birthday is a first approximation to the age.  This approximation is refined by computing the date on which your birthday falls *this year*.  If this year's birthday is still in the future, then by custom we count that as one year younger.  If we were doing something that leaned less towards a legal system, and more towards scientific work, we might well compute in other ways, such as rounding to the nearest year (also easy to do with this library).

If the birthday is on Feb 29, the above code still works:  `birthday + age` will result (75% chance) in an invalid date, e.g.:  feb/29/2015.  However this invalid date will correctly compare greater than feb/28/2015 and less than mar/1/2015, exactly as we need it to!  Invalid dates are your friend, not your enemy -- you just have to know they exist and what to do about them.

Now it is a simple matter to report your findings:

```
if (age >= years{18})
    std::cout << "full aged at " << age.count() << "\n";
else
    std::cout << "not full aged at " << age.count() << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with your code logic here.
For example:

```
Datum is 31/12/1982
Dnes is 01/01/2000
```

The year difference is 18 but the age is 17 and 2 days.

Consider using standard library functions instead of reinventing the wheel.
[difftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/) could be useful, for example

This is a very dirty example, but it would do the work:

```
   time_t dnes;
   time(&dnes);

   // Set datum here ... 
   cin >> Datum->day >> Datum->month >> Datum->year;
   datum.tm_mday = Datum->day;
   datum.tm_mon =  Datum->month - 1;
   datum.tm_yday = Datum->year - 1900;

   datum->tm_yday+=18;

   if (difftime(dnes, mktime(&datum)) <0 )
        cout << "not full aged " << endl;
    else
        cout << "full aged " << endl;
```

Comment: after mycode cin:

 time_t dnes;
 time(&dnes);

 // Set datum here ...

 aTime.tm_yday += 18;

 cout << difftime(dnes, mktime(&aTime)) << endl;
 if (difftime(dnes, mktime(&aTime)) <0)
  cout << "not full aged " << endl;
 else
  cout << "full aged " << endl;

returns random numbers, what does it even return then? i dont quite understand it seems, would you mind converting it to my code?

Comment: What do you want it to return? Your code prints to the output and returns 0. Where do you see the random numbers?

Comment: You need to implement the part that reads the `datum` by yourself. You did that already for your data types, just put the input into the `datum` struct.

Comment: well, i input 31 12 1982 and it always returns other number. i only wanted to get age difference, between those two dates as today and date which user inputs using cin as stated in example up there :S

Comment: Your example checks if there are at least  full 18 years between two dates.

Comment: Here you are. Used your Datum object, hope this is more clear this way.